# Angularjs to replace into another

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a angularjs code and html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="demos for demos in demo | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">

$scope.demo = ['demo-NV-enable','demo-NV-disable','demo-NV-shutdown','demo-NV-open'];
```

After input selected by user like 'demo-NV-enable' its has to be changed into 'demo/Nv/open' to perform some operations in angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use typehead-on-select in your view:

```
<input 
   type="text" 
   ng-model="selected" 
   uib-typeahead="demos for demos in demo | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
   typeahead-on-select="myFunction($item, $model, $label, $event)"
>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.myFunction( $item, $model, $label,$event ) {
     //do stuff here
}
```